# Displaying text on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS code that when the user clicks the "add" button, some text is displayed to a textarea.

The code seems to be working OK. However, I realize I must refactor the code so that I am using only the one `on click` function instead of the six that I have for each of the 6 add buttons.

```
$('#row_split_id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph').prepend('<div id="id_standard_suggestion_01" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a1" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.1. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_01" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div><div id="id_standard_suggestion_02" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a2" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.2. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_02" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div><div id="id_standard_suggestion_03" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a3" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.3. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_03" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div><div id="id_standard_suggestion_04" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a4" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.4. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_04" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div><div id="id_standard_suggestion_05" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a5" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.5. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_05" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div><div id="id_standard_suggestion_06" class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15"><span id="id_1a6" class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.6. </span><span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button"><button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_06" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button></span></div>');

$(function () {
    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_01').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a1');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });

    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_02').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a2');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });

    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_03').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a3');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });

    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_04').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a4');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });

    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_05').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a5');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });

    $('#id_add_standard_suggestion_paragragh01_06').on('click', function () {
        var divTA1 = document.getElementById('id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var divGS1 = document.getElementById('id_1a6');
        divTA1.innerHTML = divTA1.innerHTML + divGS1.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3354539/L9ccne9u/3/).

Comment: "Refactoring" is not needed in titles. Every question here is about refactoring.

Comment: @Jamal - Ah, I understand now! 1st time noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add HTML in DOM from jQuery, add it from server side.

**Changes in HTML**

1. Removed all `id`s as it is not used
2. Removed redundant attribute `type="button"` from buttons.

Use HTML structure as follow:

```
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.1. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.2. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.3. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.4. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.5. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.6. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
        <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

1. Use common class to bind event on all elements, `cover_letter_suggestion_add_button` in this case
2. Use the DOM traversal methods to get the elements corresponding to the clicked element, using `$(this)` to reference to clicked element and `prev` to get the previous sibling.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cover_letter_suggestion_add_button button').on('click', function () {
        // Get text of the previous span element
        var text = $(this).closest('.cover_letter_suggestion_add_button').prev().text();

        $('#id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph').val(function (i, oldVal) {
            return oldVal + text; // Append the value of the prev. span to the textarea
        });
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5qgr8vro/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cover_letter_suggestion_add_button button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).closest('.cover_letter_suggestion_add_button')
      .prev().text();
    $('#id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph').val(function(i, oldVal) {
      return oldVal + text;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.cover_letter_suggestion_content {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cover_letter_suggestion_add_button {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
.textAreaSplit {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 50%;
  resize: vertical;
}
.textAreaSplitContainer {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 45%;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 45%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: none;
  /* container is resized by resizing the textarea */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row_id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph" class="form-group  ">
  <label for="id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph" class="control-label ">Paragraph 1:</label>
  <div class="controls ">
    <span id="row_id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph">
            <textarea cols="40" data-parsley-maxlength="2000" id="id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph" maxlength="2000" name="cover_letter_details_first_paragraph" rows="10" class="textAreaSplit kmw-disabled keymanweb-font" data-parsley-id="8695" data-parsley-required="false"></textarea>
            <span class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-8695"></span>
    </span>
    <p class="help-block">2,000 character limit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.1. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.2. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.3. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.4. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.5. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
  <div class="cover_letter_suggestion_content margin-bottom-15">
    <span class="margin-bottom-15">Standard Sentence Number 1.6. </span>
    <span class="cover_letter_suggestion_add_button">
            <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
        </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3354539 Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/orm5973h/)

Comment: @Tashar, I don't understand, your demo is not working. Nothing happens on click of Add button.

Comment: @user3354539 You've to first type some text in textarea and then click on add button

Comment: @Tashar, that is not the functionality of the original code. Why did you change the functionality? What you did makes no sense! Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3354539/L9ccne9u/3/) I supplied for the actual functionality.

Comment: @user3354539 Can you please explain what is the code in question doing and what is expected

Comment: @Tashar, refer to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3354539/L9ccne9u/3/). Click any of the add buttons to have the text above the related add button displayed (appended) to the textarea.

Comment: @user3354539 Please check the updated answer. Also added live demo

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize data attribute in the button to assign the span id to it. For instance `<button id="id_add_standard_suggestion_paragraph01_01" data-span-target="id_1a1" class="btn btn-xs rounded btn-primary" type="button">{% trans "Add" %}</button>`. By doing this, you can use it inside the click event. Javascript should be as per below

```
$(function () {
    $("button[id^='id_add_standard_suggestion_paragraph']").on('click', function(){
        var divTA = $('#id_cover_letter_details_first_paragraph');
        var spanTarget = $(this).data('span-target');
        divTA.append($("#" + spanTarget).html());
    });   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1umaou73/)